# Regex to get domain with different protocols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex, which extracts domain name from string.

```
var matches = str.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/i);
```

I would like the same RegEx, including other protocols like rstp. For example:

```
"http://www.example.com/a/".match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/i)
```

Result: `["http://www.example.com/", "www.example.com"]`

I have tried this:

```
"http://www.example.com/a/".match(/^(http|https|rtsp)\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/i)
```

But it returns http too: `["http://www.example.com/", "http", "www.example.com"]`

I would like the same output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to turn your group of protocol alternations into a non-capturing group by prefixing it with `?:`:

```
"http://www.example.com/a/".match(/^(?:http|https|rtsp)\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/i)
//["http://www.example.com/", "www.example.com"]
```